# How to sort Firebase keys that were created with "push()"?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

According to the Firebase docs:

> The unique name generated by push() is prefixed with a
>   client-generated timestamp so that the resulting list will be
>   chronologically-sorted.

So how when I retrieve a list from a node where all its children are created via `push`, how do I convert this object into a chronologically-sorted array? In AngularFire, there is the $asArray() method which seems to do this for you. How can I do this without AngularFire?

An code example of what I am trying to do is:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://your.firebaseio.com/')

ref.on('value', function(snap){
  var obj = snap.val()

  console.log(obj)

  /*
  obj looks like: {-JeHAy0QO5jhCAecc-Ha: {name: "item 1"} ..}. 
  I'd like to loop through this collection in
  chronology order, but in JS, one should not rely on the order that key values
  come while using a for-in loop. So I figured that instead, I probably need
  to transform it into an array first then use a regular for loop.

  Therefore, I'd like to transform obj into an array:
  [{name: 'item 1'}, {name: 'item 2'}, ..]
  where the order of the array is chronologically ordered (ie somehow decode 
  and use the keys of obj to sort the object). How do I do this?
  */
})
```

under `script.js` in this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/yEcBK7PVTf7VxjnVhNXL?p=info

Comment: It would help if you show your code. But most likely what you're looking for is the `previousChild` argument that is passed to `on(child_` events. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html

Comment: Let's say I have a bunch of objects that were previously pushed via `push()` at `/parent`. Then I retrieve those objects via something like: `parentRef.once('value', function(snap){var children = snap.val()})` The `children` object will be something like `{pushID: data, ...}`. The question is how to convert `children` into an array that is shorted by the `pushID`'s time chronology

Comment: When you retrieve a single value, the children are already ordered either by their priority (or if they have no priority their key) or by whatever you specified in `orderByChild`. So if you use a basic `push` to add children and retrieve them, they will be in chronological order.

Comment: Which leaves it unclear to me what you are asking. Can you write up a minimal example of your code+data that demonstrates the problem you're trying to solve (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Click the edit link under your question to add this information.

Comment: Okay, I have added a plunkr that hopefully explains what I am trying to do. Please let me know if I am still being unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to put all children into an array in the order of their key, you can use the [DataSnapshot's `forEach` method](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/foreach.html):

```
ref.on('value', function(snap){
  var children = [];
  snap.forEach(function(child) {
    children.push(child.val());
  });
  console.log(children.length);
```

After the `forEach` your array will contain all children in the correct order.

But be aware that this will fire each time any child is added/removed or any of the existing children is modified. If you use this array to build a HTML DOM, you'll end up repainting the entire collection every time.

That's why Firebase also fires events for the specific children: `child_added`, `child_changed`, `child_removed` and `child_moved`. The signature for `on` is defined as:

> `on()` - `on(eventType, callback, [cancelCallback], [context])`

And the callback is a function documented as:

> A callback that fires when the specified event occurs. The callback will be passed a DataSnapshot. For ordering purposes, "child_added", "child_changed", and "child_moved" will also be passed a string containing the key of the previous child, by priority order (or null if it is the first child).

So with the `previousChild` parameter you could then also reconstruct the correct order (you'd just have to do it yourself).

Fore more information see the [Firebase documentation on these events](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html).